# My data enter in database in C# is like ???? in Persian Language

Tags: c#, utf-8

when i enter my data in persian language i see in database my data like "?????"

```
class ConnectionDatabase
{
    public newDbAtDataSet dset = new newDbAtDataSet();
    public SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    public SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    public SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    public string locate = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\mohsen\source\repos\Atash\Atash\newDbAt.mdf';Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
}
```

Comment: Make sure you are using `nvarchar` for your strings.

Comment: _"i see in database"_ Where? In Sql Studio? Are you sure the font can display persion chars?

Comment: It depends on the viewer you are using to look at the text,  and the encoding being used.  The data is probably in the database correctly and you are not looking at the data with a viewer that can display Persian.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with an Application of mine, where I try to save Persian language in the Database. I didn't have any problems, the letters where shown as normal.

I saved them into the Database like this:

```
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table (name) VALUES (@Name)", Connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", "آزمون");
    sqlconn.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

In your Database you have to use the Type `nvarchar`. It should work properly then.